Error message when creating a catalog: No metastore assigned for the current workspace
Trying to add a Unity Catalog for use in Azure Databricks, but receiving the error message "No metastore assigned for the current workspace."
(https://i.sstatic.net/0kOkJYmC.png)
I have checked that I am a workspace admin in Databricks. Other explanations on the web say that there is a workspaces tab when navigating to the catalog section, however, I do not see this.

You need Metastore Admin privileges (different from Workspace Admin) to create a catalog under Metastore.

How do I add the metastore admin role? I am the only user using this Azure service so I don't understand why I wouldn't have that role already

You need to be a metastore admin to create a catalog under metastore because that is above the workspace admin level privileges. One who is account admin can give you the priviledge of the metastore admin and you can do that by logging into account console if you are account admin.

You need to go to Account Console instead of workspace console.
The former url is accounts.azuredatabricks.net. It is static with web title as "Account console"

Please also note that you need to sign in as a Global Administrator  to manage metastore admin in Account console

The latter has a url with format like https://adb-675114237288296.16.azuredatabricks.net. Its web title is Databricks
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/admin/#establish-first-account-admin
https://community.databricks.com/t5/get-started-discussions/not-able-to-access-account-console-page/td-p/50024
